# npm oracledb logging and tracing

Tags: node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

My goal is to enable logging and tracing for the oracle database using the oracle client and npm package `oracledb` so that I can check when the query was started and when results were returned or if the query was timed out.

More precisely I want to check if it's the oracle client which is taking the time or if there is something wrong with the `oracledb` package.

I want to check logs for any errors and want to trace slow queries or queries for which a timeout error has occurred or any deadlock that occurs.

So far I'm successfully able to enable logging and tracing for the oracle database client and it's working only when I use `sqlplus` CLI but when it comes to the `oracledb` npm package it's not working.

I have created `sqlnet.ora` in `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin` directory, and then pasted this content to enable logging and tracing for oracle-client.

```
LOG_DIRECTORY_CLIENT=C:\Oracle\instantclient_21_3\network\admin\cl-log
LOG_DIRECTORY_SERVER=C:\Oracle\instantclient_21_3\network\admin\srv-log
LOG_FILE_CLIENT=client
LOG_FILE_SERVER=svr.log
TRACE_LEVEL_CLIENT=ADMIN
DIAG_ADR_ENABLED=ON
ADR_BASE=C:\Oracle\instantclient_21_3\network\admin\log-adr
```

And as far as the implementation of `oracledb` with NodeJs is concerned I create connection pools using `oracledb.createPool({...config})` and then when I need to query into DB I use `oracledb.getPool('poolName').execute(query)`.

To me, the error is that it creates random `.trc` files and does not put logs to the `sqlnet.log` file only when using the `oraceldb` npm package.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with a complete example of your code/setup so that we can replicate the error. At the moment you only vaguely allude to the steps you have taken and most of the detail is on a third-party website hidden behind a link (that may suffer from link-rot in the future and be unavailable); instead you should include **ALL** the necessary information in your question to replicate your setup and the problem.

Comment: You definitely should not enable Oracle library tracing all the time because this will slow everything down way too much.  The ADR system will  anyway create a trace if there is a significant issue.  What you need to do instead is implement some application level tracing using your favorite Node.js package.  PS when I use Oracle Client tracing I tend not to set ADR_BASE.  You do have to pre-create the directory ADR will write too, e.g. I create the (default) directory instantclient_xx_y/log/diag/clients before starting my app.

Comment: @ChristopherJones Thanks for your comment, Precisely I want to check when the query was started and when results were returned or if the query was timed out.
So do you think that logging queries manually in the NodeJS app is fine?

Comment: Yes, add tracing to your app code or extend the node-oracledb classes.

Comment: So what if I want to find out if the oracle client is taking time to perform the query or is it the node app that is taking extra time?

Comment: Because I have guts that the query is taking time in the RDBMS system.

Comment: @ChristopherJones More precisely I want to check if it's the oracle client which is taking the time or if there is something wrong with the `oracledb` package.